# Вывести даты первого и последнего сообщений в рубрике WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Друзья, есть вот такой код PHP, для вывода списка подрубрик из указанной рубрики:

```
$args = array('parent' => 'XX', 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'desc');
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
echo '<p><strong>' . $category->name.'</strong></p>';
}
```

Выводит список подрубрик в следующем виде:

**Подрубрика 1**

**Подрубрика 2**

**Подрубрика Х**

Что нужно добавить (и куда), чтобы на выходе было

**Подрубрика 1 (первый пост: ГГГГ-ММ-ЧЧ / последний пост: ГГГГ-ММ-ЧЧ)**

**Подрубрика 2 (первый пост: ГГГГ-ММ-ЧЧ / последний пост: ГГГГ-ММ-ЧЧ)**

**Подрубрика Х (первый пост: ГГГГ-ММ-ЧЧ / последний пост: ГГГГ-ММ-ЧЧ)**

Сам не справлюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array('parent' => 'XX', 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'desc');
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    $cat = get_cat_ID( $category->cat_name );
    $count = get_category($cat)->category_count;
    $post = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1, 'category' => $cat, 'order' => 'ASC'));
    echo '<p><strong>' . $category->name . ' Первый пост: ' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post[0] ->post_date)) . ' / Последний пост: '. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post[$count-1] ->post_date)) .'</strong></p>';
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.